# block data length 395373281 > 1637-12

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

I have been using cnosdb2.3 version before, and I most want to upgrade to the main branch.

When I finished editing and pulled up the cluster, I found that the startup failed.The log as follow:

```
The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: IndexErr { source: FileErrors { msg: "block data length 395373281 > 1637-12" } }
Location: /Users/xxx/Documents/github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/tskv/src/kvcore.rs:163

Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
```

I checked the relevant documents and found that 2.3 is not compatible with the main branch.

Is there any upgrade plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a kernel bug, you can raise an issue on github